# ScrollTo(0,250) with animation Android ScrollView

Tags: android

When i scrollTo(0,250) i want to include an animation with the scrollaction. i did this code but it is not scrolling according to the animation.
scrollMe is the scrolling widget id.

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(scrollMe, "translationY",
                        250, 0);
                anim.setDuration(800);
                anim.start();
                scrollMe.scrollTo(0, 250);
```

Answer (score 13):

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(view, "scrollY", 0, 250).setDuration(duration);
objectAnimator.start();
```

Comment: should i use scrollMe.scrollTo(0, scrollMe.getBottom()); too ? if so before or after objectAnimator ?

Comment: no, "scrollY" animator already had scrolled at the position whatever you want with duration.also,if so it may influence the animator,you can try it.

Comment: I tried to use your approach. It's animate `ScrollView` but there is small issue during this animation, part of `ScrollView` that became visible on the screen is gray and content of this part not drawn. Do you know what can cause this effect?

Comment: the perfect answer