# Android autoscrolling text view

Tags: android, animation

I would like to implement a auto scrolling text view in a native Android app.

Something like a vertically scrolling marquee. The idea being that it looks something similar to an autocue, the text will remain static and scroll once more text has been provided.

I am happy to work out the logic of scrolling the text when new text arrives. I am just looking for ideas on how to have that text feed/scroll effect animation.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe start here to make the textview scrollable:

[Making TextView scrollable on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-in-android)

After that, you should be able to use an object animator, such as:

[ScrollTo(0,250) with animation Android ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20944186/scrollto0-250-with-animation-android-scrollview)

Answer (score 0):

Do like:
in XML:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:maxLines="5" />
```

And in java:

```
textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())
```

Answer (score 0):

You Just check it and refer this answer.

[Android automatic horizontally scrolling TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472362/android-automatic-horizontally-scrolling-textview)

I think you want solution like this. for *auto scrolling TextView*.

there is many *other solutions* also which working with *programmatic* to *scroll String* in your *TextView area*.

[auto-scrolling TextView in android to bring text into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506696/auto-scrolling-textview-in-android-to-bring-text-into-view)

[Automatic horizontal scroll in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420483/automatic-horizontal-scroll-in-textview)

Refer this links and get Solution as per you want.
Thanks for this *question's owners* and *accepted Answer givers*.